# Deleting Duplicates EXCEL VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I need some help with a macro and I'm not sure where to even start as I am quite new to this. I will have a list of data/Ref numbers in column "A" starting in "A7". Many of these Ref numbers will have duplicates. (mainly 2 duplicates)

Although, there are certain cases in which I will have 3 or 4 duplicates of the same Ref numbers. I need a macro to search for duplicate values In column "A" that appear more than twice and delete them and the row they are in while keeping the first and last instance.

I hope I explained this clearly enough to understand. I attached a snapshot of an example below.

Columns "A" through "C" contain a data set and it contains duplicates with one instance where there are 3 of them. (Highlighted in Red text) The final result I want is shown in columns "G" through "I".

Please note this needs to be done with a macro/VBA and the length of data in the columns and rows may vary each time this macro is ran, so it would need to apply till last used row and column.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the basic script which I applied but the problem is it will delete all duplicates. 
    Sub Dup ()

```
M = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = M To 7 Step -1
        Set rlook = Range(Cells(i - 1, "A"), Cells(7, 1))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rlook, Cells(i, "A")) > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "A").clear
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks[image]

Comment: you can Record Macro of Data tab > Remove Duplicates https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim Duplicates() As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Val1, Val2 As String

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

lRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Index = 0

For i = 7 To lRow
    Val1 = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Index = 0
    For j = i + 1 To lRow
        Val2 = sht.Cells(j, 1).Value
        If Val1 = Val2 Then
            ReDim Preserve Duplicates(Index)
            Duplicates(Index) = j
            Index = Index + 1
        End If
        If j = lRow Then
            If Index > 1 Then
                For k = UBound(Duplicates) - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    sht.Rows(Duplicates(k)).EntireRow.Delete
                Next k
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the previous row value and the next row value. If the previous row's value is the same as the current and the next one is too... It's a 3rd+ record.

```
If (Current = Previous) AND (Current = Next) Then
Cells(i, "A").clear
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary to save the last row where a value last appeared, so to add it to the deleted range when found again. The trick is, don't save it if it is the first appearence: on first appearance, put zero in the dictionary instead of the row number, so that you can avoid deleting the first appearance.

```
Sub keepFirstAndLast()
  Dim toDelete As Range: Set toDelete = Sheet1.Rows(999999) '(to not start with a null range)
  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim a As Range
  For Each a In Sheet1.Range("A7", Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp))
    If Not dict.Exists(a.Value2) Then
      dict(a.Value2) = 0 ' first appearence, dont save the row
    Else
      ' if last observed occurrence was a duplicate, add it to deleted range
      If dict(a.Value2) > 0 Then Set toDelete = Union(toDelete, Sheet1.Rows(dict(a.Value2)))
      dict(a.Value2) = a.row ' not first appearence, save the row for eventual deletion
    End If
  Next
  toDelete.Delete
End Sub
```