# VBA: Keep first and last rows of duplicate column values of an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, autofilter

I have an Excel worksheet with 20K rows like this:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P |
| 2 | P |
| 3 | P |
| 4 | Q |
| 5 | R |
| 6 | R |
| 7 | R |
| 8 | R |
| 9 | S |
| 10 | S |

I want a VBA code to delete the rows containing duplicates, but **keep the first and last row** of the duplicates. The result should be like this:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P |
| 3 | P |
| 4 | Q |
| 5 | R |
| 8 | R |
| 9 | S |
| 10 | S |

I have modified the following code found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-delete-duplicate-rows-keep-last-entry.623581/post-4516199) to do just that, but every time I have to manually select the range containing the duplicates in column header2.

```
Sub Delete_Dups_Keep_Last_v2()
 Dim SelRng As Range
 Dim Cell_in_Rng As Range
 Dim RngToDelete As Range
 Dim SelLastRow As Long
 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set SelRng = Application.InputBox("Select cells", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
    SelLastRow = SelRng.Rows.Count + SelRng.Row - 1
    For Each Cell_in_Rng In SelRng
        
        If Cell_in_Rng.Row < SelLastRow Then
            If Cell_in_Rng.Row > SelRng.Row Then
                If Not Cell_in_Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(SelLastRow - Cell_in_Rng.Row).Find(What:=Cell_in_Rng.Value, Lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                    'this value exists again in the range
                    If RngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                        Set RngToDelete = Cell_in_Rng
                    Else
                        Set RngToDelete = Application.Union(RngToDelete, Cell_in_Rng)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
    Next Cell_in_Rng
 
    If Not RngToDelete Is Nothing Then RngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Another code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102631/19337396) by user [A.S.H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) automates the manual selection and speed by using Dictionary, but fails to produce the wanted result.

```
Sub keepFirstAndLast()
  Dim toDelete As Range: Set toDelete = Sheet1.Rows(999999) '(to not start with a null range)
  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim a As Range
  For Each a In Sheet1.Range("B2", Sheet1.Range("B999999").End(xlUp))
    If Not dict.Exists(a.Value2) Then
      dict(a.Value2) = 0 ' first appearence, dont save the row
    Else
      ' if last observed occurrence was a duplicate, add it to deleted range
      If dict(a.Value2) > 0 Then Set toDelete = Union(toDelete, Sheet1.Rows(dict(a.Value2)))
      dict(a.Value2) = a.row ' not first appearence, save the row for eventual deletion
    End If
  Next
  toDelete.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
Sub KeepFirstLast()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim currentValue As String

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If i = 2 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit For
    End If
    currentValue = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
    x = i - 1
    Do While Sheets(1).Cells(x, 2).Value = currentValue And Sheets(1).Cells(x - 1, 2).Value = currentValue
        Sheets(1).Rows(x).Delete
        x = x - 1
    Loop
    i = x + 1
Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: As someone with basic level understanding of VBA, this was the easiest code to understand and to implement. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Keep First and Last In Sorted Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteNotFirstNorLast()
    Const ProcName As String = "DeleteNotFirstNorLast"
    Dim RowsDeleted As Boolean ' to inform
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' enable error trapping
    
    ' Constants (adjust!)
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const CriteriaColumnIndex As Long = 2
    Const Criteria As String = "#$%"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Turn off AutoFilter.
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False 
    
    ' Reference the table range.
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = RefCurrentRegion(ws.Range(FirstCellAddress))
    
    ' Write an ascending integer sequence adjacent to the right
    ' of the table range.
    AppendColumnOfAscendingIntegers trg
    
    ' Include this helper column to the table range.
    Set trg = trg.Resize(, trg.Columns.Count + 1)
    
    ' Reference the criteria column range.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = trg.Columns(CriteriaColumnIndex)
    
    ' It is assumed that the criteria column is already sorted favorably.
    ' If not, you could do something like the following:
    
    ' Sort the table range by the criteria column ascending.
    'trg.Sort crg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    
    ' Write the data rows (no headers) count to a variable.
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = trg.Rows.Count - 1
    
    ' Reference the criteria column data range (headers excluded).
    Dim cdrg As Range: Set cdrg = crg.Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    
    ' Write the values from the criteria column data range to an array.
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = GetRange(cdrg)
    
    ' Replace the unwanted values in the array with the criteria.
    KeepFirstAndLastInColumn cData
    
    ' Write the (modified) values from the array back to the range.
    cdrg.Value = cData
    
    ' Reference the table data range (no headers).
    Dim tdrg As Range: Set tdrg = trg.Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    
    ' Filter the table range in the criteria column by the criteria.
    trg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumnIndex, Criteria
    
    ' Attempt to reference the table data visible (filtered) range.
    Dim tdvrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
        Set tdvrg = tdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' re-enable error trapping
    
    ' Remove the filter.
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Attempt to delete the table data visible range.
    If Not tdvrg Is Nothing Then
        tdvrg.Delete xlShiftUp
        RowsDeleted = True
    End If
    
    ' Reference the helper column.
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = trg.Columns(trg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Sort the table range by the helper column ascending.
    trg.Sort hrg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    
    ' Clear the helper column.
    hrg.Clear
    
SafeExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' to see any changes while reading message
    
    ' Inform.
    If RowsDeleted Then
        MsgBox "Rows deleted.", vbInformation, ProcName
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing deleted.", vbExclamation, ProcName
    End If

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a reference to the range starting with the first cell
'               of a range and ending with the last cell of the first cell's
'               Current Region.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCurrentRegion( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefCurrentRegion"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With FirstCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = FirstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - FirstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - FirstCell.Column)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes an ascending integer sequence adjacent to the right
'               of a range.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub AppendColumnOfAscendingIntegers( _
        ByVal trg As Range, _
        Optional ByVal FirstInteger As Long = 1)
    Const ProcName As String = "AppendColumnOfAscendingIntegers"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With trg
        With .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count)
            .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate("ROW(" & CStr(FirstInteger) & ":" _
                & CStr(FirstInteger + .Rows.Count - 1) & ")")
        End With
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('trg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal trg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If trg.Rows.Count + trg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = trg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = trg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In the first column of a 2D one-based array of sorted values,
'               keeps the first and last occurrence of each value and replaces
'               the remaining occurrences with a string.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub KeepFirstAndLastInColumn( _
        ByRef cData As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal Criteria As String = "#$%")
    Const ProcName As String = "KeepFirstAndLastInColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim OldString As String: OldString = CStr(cData(1, 1))
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim cr As Long
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim NewString As String
    
    For r = 2 To UBound(cData, 1)
        NewString = CStr(cData(r, 1))
        If NewString = OldString Then
            If FirstRow = 0 Then
                FirstRow = r
            End If
        Else
            If FirstRow > 0 Then
                For cr = FirstRow To r - 2
                    cData(cr, 1) = Criteria
                Next cr
                FirstRow = 0
            End If
            OldString = NewString
        End If
    Next r

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from `SpecialCells` to select those rows based on formula:

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long 'last row
Dim LC As Long 'last column
Dim SR As Long 'starting row
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1") 'change this to TOP LEFT CELL OF YOUR DATA

SR = rng.Row
LR = rng.CurrentRegion.Cells(rng.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 1).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column used

'we add new column with formula to delete
With Range(Cells(SR + 1, LC + 1), Cells(LR, LC + 1))
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]<>R[-1]C[-1],RC[-1]<>R[1]C[-1]),""x"",0)"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End With

'clear formula
LR = rng.CurrentRegion.Cells(rng.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 1).Row
Range(Cells(SR + 1, LC + 1), Cells(LR, LC + 1)).Clear

Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The tricky part is here:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]<>R[-1]C[-1],RC[-1]<>R[1]C[-1]),""x"",0)"
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

First line will create and IF(OR) formula to check if the row must be deleted or not. It will return `x` if not, else `0`

Second line will delete entire rows only if it contains a number (zero)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlhtI.gif

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//change next line to your actual table name in your worksheet
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"header1", Int64.Type}, {"header2", type text}}),

//Group by header2
// then return the first and last table rows if there is more than a single row
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"header2"}, {
        {"header1", each if Table.RowCount(_) = 1 then _ 
            else Table.FromRecords({Table.First(_),Table.Last(_)}), 
                    type table[header1=Int64.Type, header2=text]}
        }),

//expand the subtables and set the column order
    #"Expanded header1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "header1", {"header1"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded header1",{"header1", "header2"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]